# Access to Automatic Array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Could be in the loop for automatically every time you run it the next time go to the next array?

In fact, I've created 10 array I want to automatically print array (matris1) values then go to array (matris2),...

Please do not use linq techniques,I am a beginner

```
namespace Matris
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int[,] matris = new int[2, 2];
    int[,] matris1 = new int[2, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    int[,] matris2 = new int[2, 2] { { 3, 5 }, { 9, 7 } };
    int[,] matris3 = new int[2, 2] { { 11, 21 }, { 20, 30 } };
    int[,] matris4 = new int[2, 2] { { 14, 22 }, { 13, 44 } };
    int[,] matris5 = new int[2, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 68, 98 } };
    int[,] matris6 = new int[2, 2] { { 87, 54 }, { 17, 0 } };
    int[,] matris7 = new int[2, 2] { { 99, 35 }, { 47, 10 } };
    int[,] matris8 = new int[2, 2] { { 23, 41 }, { 61, 16 } };
    int[,] matris9 = new int[2, 2] { { 1, 38 }, { 121, 1000 } };
    int[,] matris10 = new int[2, 2] { { 560, 202 }, { 101, 2000 } };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int s = 1;
        while (s < 11)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(matris1[i, j]); 
                }
            }

        }
    }//end button
}//end class
}//end namespace
```

Comment: you can create array of arrays. `int[,][]` and put your matrices there.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary,very big up to you

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[,] matris = new int[2, 2];
    int[,] matris1 = new int[2, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    int[,] matris2 = new int[2, 2] { { 3, 5 }, { 9, 7 } };
    int[,] matris3 = new int[2, 2] { { 11, 21 }, { 20, 30 } };
    int[,] matris4 = new int[2, 2] { { 14, 22 }, { 13, 44 } };
    int[,] matris5 = new int[2, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 68, 98 } };
    int[,] matris6 = new int[2, 2] { { 87, 54 }, { 17, 0 } };
    int[,] matris7 = new int[2, 2] { { 99, 35 }, { 47, 10 } };
    int[,] matris8 = new int[2, 2] { { 23, 41 }, { 61, 16 } };
    int[,] matris9 = new int[2, 2] { { 1, 38 }, { 121, 1000 } };
    int[,] matris10 = new int[2, 2] { { 560, 202 }, { 101, 2000 } };

    public void Listss()
    {
        List<int[,]> data = new List<int[,]>() { matris, matris1, matris2, matris3, matris4, matris5, matris6, matris7, matris8, matris9, matris10 };

        foreach (var item in data)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < item.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item[i, 0] + " - " + item[i, 1]);
            }
        }

    }
```